# split array into subarrays

Tags: r, matrix, split

I have an array e.g. `arr = cbind(c(1,1,2,2,3), c(1,2,3,4,5))`, I want to agglomerate the rows that has the same first element, and store the result as a list. Any ways to do that? Expected output of this example `result = list( cbind(c(1,1), c(1,2)), cbind(c(2,2), c(3,4)), cbind(c(3), c(5)) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop (`lapply`) through the `unique` values of the first column of `arr` and subset the rows based on the matching elements  of first column with the unique element.

```
lapply(unique(arr[,1]), function(i) arr[arr[,1]==i,,drop=FALSE])
```

Or we `split` the sequence of rows of 'arr' with the first column of 'arr' and use the row index to subset the 'arr'.

```
lapply(split(1:nrow(arr), arr[,1]), function(i) arr[i,, drop=FALSE])
```

Or as @Jota mentioned in the comments, we can `split` the 'arr' by the first column to give `vector` as `list` elements.  We loop using `lapply` and convert the `vector` to `matrix`.

```
lapply(split(arr, arr[,1]), matrix, ncol=2)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
arr1 <- cbind(rep(seq(1000), each=1000), seq(1e6))
system.time(res1 <- lapply(unique(arr1[,1]), function(i) 
                arr1[arr1[,1]==i,,drop=FALSE]))
# user  system elapsed 
# 18.980   0.000  15.906 


system.time(res2 <- lapply(split(1:nrow(arr1), arr1[,1]), 
                  function(i) arr1[i,, drop=FALSE]))
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.00    0.00    0.07 
names(res2) <- NULL
 identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE

system.time(res3 <- lapply(split(arr1, arr1[,1]), matrix, ncol=2))
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.000   0.000   0.186 
names(res3) <- NULL
identical(res1, res3)
#[1] TRUE

system.time(res4 <- split(data.frame(arr1), arr1[,1]))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  1.151   0.000   1.039
```

Based on the above benchmarks, `split` approach is better.

Comment: `lapply(split(arr, arr[,1]), matrix, ncol=2)` is a similar strategy.

Comment: @Jota Thanks, that is concise.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this shorter approach:

```
split(data.frame(arr), arr[,1])
#$`1`
#  X1 X2
#1  1  1
#2  1  2

#$`2`
#  X1 X2
#3  2  3
#4  2  4

#$`3`
#  X1 X2
#5  3  5
```

Comment: Well, your shorter approach is a data.frame and not a matrix as list element.  Based on the expected output provided by the OP, it is still a matrix.